Expressing a function in terms of the nontrivial zeros of the Riemann zeta function
Consider the function $\phi(x)$:
$$ \phi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}}\left(\left\{ \frac{x}{n}\right\}-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$
$\left\{\cdot\right\}$ being the fractional part function. Taking the Mellin transform of the this function, we obtain :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\phi(x)x^{-s-1}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\left\{ \frac{x}{n}\right\}-\frac{1}{2}\right)x^{-s-1}dx$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{s+2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\left\{y\right\}-\frac{1}{2}\right)y^{-s-1}dy=-\frac{\zeta(s)}{s\zeta(s+2)}\;\;\;\;-1<\Re(s)<0$$
Where we used:
$$\zeta(s)=-s\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\left\{y\right\}-\frac{1}{2}\right)y^{-s-1}dy\;\;\;\;-1<\Re(s)<0 \;\;\text{(Due to Titchmarsh) }$$
By Mellin's inversion theorem:
$$\phi(x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty}\frac{\zeta(s)}{s\zeta(s+2)}x^{s}ds\;\;\;\;-1<\sigma<0$$
Shifting the line of integration to the left, and using well-known estimates of the zeta function, we pick up the residues at every $\rho(n)-2$, where $\rho(n)$ is the nth nontrivial zeros of the zeta function. Thus:
$$ \phi(x)=-\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{\gamma _{n}<T}\frac{\zeta(\rho_{n}-2)}{(\rho_{n}-2)\zeta^{'}(\rho_{n})}x^{\rho_{n}-2}$$
Assuming the truth of the Riemann hypothesis, this function seems to decay like $x^{-3/2}$, but our original function doesn't! Where did I go wrong?

Why do you think you can shift the integral to the left beyond the line $-3/2$?  The numerator there grows like $t^2$ quite often by the standard estimates of the growth of zeta on negative abscissas ($1/2-\sigma$) and the denominator is at most just $t^{1+\epsilon}$ so the integral to the left diverges; more generally if you go to abscissa $-\sigma$ for large such the behavior on the vertical sides is very often as $t^{1/2}$

Also if RH fails in the worst way the final function you have grows no fast than $x^{-1}$ while I suspect one can give an argument that the original function grows bigger than $x^{-3/4}$ occasionally so a contradiction in any case regardless of the truth of RH

@Conrad Is there another way to evaluate the integral?

Not that I know off hand

@Conrad I have two questions: Where does the bound $x^{-3/4}$ come from? Also, if we integrate $\phi(x)$ twice, the divergence issues seem to disappear, but then if we differentiate the result twice, we seem to go back to the conditionally convergent series containing the nontrivial zeros of the zeta function!

For the second thing sure integrating eliminates divergence many times (for example the Riemann theory of trigonometric series is based on integrating twice or the PNT is proven sometimes for the primitive of $\psi$ which behaves like $x^2/2$ and then cleverly going down to $\psi$; going down by differentiation is the hard part

For the first thing I think one can connect the expressions here with the remainder in the divisor sum (averaged by $n$) and that is known to be at least $x^{1/4}$ occasionally so the $x^{-3/4}$ mentioned - didn't work it out but that where I would look for
